# Allow clicking on links before jQuery .load is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax to load content from another internal page into a div because that content takes a long time to generate (about 10+ seconds typically).

I have noticed that I am not able to click on any links on the parent page until the .load page is fully loaded. More precisely, I can click on the link but the browser waits for the content to finish loading first before it brings me to the next page.

How can I allow this?

My code is below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content').load('http://samesite.com/slow-loading-page.php');
    });
</script>
<div id="content"><img src="images/loading.gif"></div>';
```